# Prevent ANY sound from Android phone

Tags: audio

I have the Galaxy S4 and would like to be able to ensure that, when on silent/vibrate mode, the phone makes absolutely no noise. I haven't been able to find a way to prevent the alarm from making noise when going off in silent mode, and though I could set the alarm type to vibrate, I'm concerned that if the alarm can go off in silent mode, other things can make noise as well.

Is there a way to ensure the phone makes no noise? Is it really only the alarm that makes noise in silent mode?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Volume Control +](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cb.volumePlus&hl=en). This app lets you control the volume for the following: Media, Ring, Notifications, In-call, alarm, system. Each sound profile (e.g. Silent, Vibrate, General) can be configured.